# number length limit in SOQL Where condition

Tags: soql

When I execute SOQL in Developer Console:

```
Select Id, Amount From Opportunity Where Amount > 10000000000
```

An parsing error occurs:

```
Unknown error parsing query
```

Is there length limit of number on SOQL Where condition?

Comment: Funny enough the query will work if you added ".0" at the end to be 10000000000.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to your query you are passing `10000000000` which is a **11 digit** Integer value.

In Salesforce or Java **Integer can not be bigger than 2,147,483,647**. Current value you are passing is considered as Integer and exceeds the given number so error is given.

Try adding decimal. Decimal can be bigger upto `2 raise to power 63 - 1`. So this will work:

```
Select Id, Amount From Opportunity Where Amount > 10000000000.0
```

Compiler will understand that it is a decimal.

Answer (score 3):

As per document ..

Maximum number we can use is `2,147,483,647.`

> Integer
>
> A 32-bit number that does not include a decimal point. Integers have a
>   minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647.
>   For example:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm

Answer (score 3):

I am having an alternate method

You can use the Long datatype to solve this problem.

For Example:

```
Select Id, Amount From Opportunity Where Amount > 10000000000L
```

We are now explicitly telling the compiler the amount is the Long Datatype.

The Long datatype in Salesforce and Java has a much larger range than the Integer datatype and can hold values up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

By adding the suffix "L" to the end of the number in the WHERE clause, you are telling the compiler to treat the number as a Long value.