# Why do you have to add ".0" to a SOQL where clause if the number is greater than 2^31?

Tags: soql, number

Given a number field on Case, try to execute these SOQL queries:

`SELECT Id FROM Case where NumberField__c = 2147483647` => works fine

`SELECT Id FROM Case where NumberField__c = 2147483648` => fails with this error message:

> MALFORMED_QUERY: from Case where NumberField__c = 2147483648 ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:45 For input string: "2147483648"

It looks like SOQL interpretes numbers up to 2^31-1 (2147483647) as numbers, but numbers from 2^31 and greater as strings. To fix this, you can just include a decimal point (e. g. 2147483648.0), then they will be intepreted as a number.

**Is there any documentation for this behaviour?** I could not find any. Do you know why SOQL is built this way?

I consider this behaviour to be bad design. I just had an index increase over 2^31 and suddenly a query that has been working for years failed.

Comment: I think basic problem is that 2147483647 is valid integer, 2147483648 should be integer, but in real world it is invalid integer, and 2147483648.0 is decimal and valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Salesforce or Java Integer can not be bigger than 2,147,483,647. Current value you are passing is considered as Integer and exceeds the given number so error is given.

Try adding decimal. Decimal can be bigger upto 2 raise to power 63 - 1. I responded to same question here as well: [number length limit in SOQL Where condition](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105857/number-length-limit-in-soql-where-condition/105862#105862)

This is default behavior of Java language and other languages including database column types so, it is something applicable in common coding practice. It is not limited to language only.

According to type declared, limits are applied. Here is [wiki link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/limits.h) which is also applicable to Salesforce as well.

Comment: This query is run using the standard API (no Apex here). The field is just a number field with length 18. Do you know any documentation for this?

Comment: Updated my answer for better clarity. @georgw.